# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Can't figure it out

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python... So, i wrote this function that should normalize the price values contained in the "price" column of my dataframe:

```
def normalize_price(df): 
    for elements in df['price']: 
        if (df["price"]>= 1000) and (df['price']<= 1499): 
            df['price'] = 1000 
            return
        elif 1500 <= df['price'] <= 2499:
            df['price'] = 1500 
            return
        elif 2500 <= df['price'] <= 2999:
            df['price'] = 2500 
            return
        elif 3000 <= df['price'] <= 3999:
            df['price'] = 3000 
            return
```

So, when I call it I get the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
<ipython-input-86-1e239d3cbba4> in normalize_price(df)
     20 def normalize_price(df):
     21     for elements in df['price']:
---> 22         if (df["price"]>= 1000) and (df['price']<= 1499):
     23             df['price'] = 1000
     24             return

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

And since I'm going crazy, I'd like to know why :)
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: You aren't using `elements`, try `if elements >= 1000`, rather than the whole column

Comment: you are comparing a whole Series to a integer. `df["price"]` is a the complete column from your DataFrame, so when you use `if (df["price"]>= 1000)`  the result is ambiguous.

Comment: use `df.loc or np.select`

Comment: Right. Now i notice it... So, i should write df[`price`] [elements ]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.select` is probably the easiest approach

```
def normalize_price(df): 
    # create a list of conditions
    cond = [
        (df["price"]>= 1000) & (df['price']<= 1499),
        1500 <= df['price'] <= 2499,
        2500 <= df['price'] <= 2999,
        3000 <= df['price'] <= 3999
    ]
    # create a list of choices based on the conditions above
    choice = [
        1000,
        1500,
        2500,
        3000
    ]
    # use numpy.select and assign array to df['price']
    df['price'] = np.select(cond, choice, df['price'])
    return df
```

## update with example

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10000, 50), columns=['price'])

def normalize_price(df): 
    cond = [
        (df["price"]>= 1000) & (df['price']<= 1499),
        (df['price'] >= 1500) & (df['price'] <= 2499),
        (df['price'] >= 2500) & (df['price'] <= 2999),
        (df['price'] >= 3000) & (df['price'] <= 3999)
    ]

    choice = [
        1000,
        1500,
        2500,
        3000
    ]

    df['price_new'] = np.select(cond, choice, df['price'])
    return df

normalize_price(df)

    price  price_new
0     235        235
1    5192       5192
2     905        905
3    7813       7813
4    2895       2500 <-----
5    5056       5056
6     144        144
7    4225       4225
8    7751       7751
9    3462       3000 <----
```

Comment: but this way in the cond list I'm still looking into df["price"] which is a list...

Comment: `df['price']` is not a list it is a `pd.Series`

Comment: then rewrite your conditions: `(df['price'] >= 1500) & (df['price'] <= 2499)`

Comment: I know this should be really basic, but that's what I'm trying to do in a while rightn now... ahahaha

Comment: And that works perfectly! but I have one more question. so, apparently if I write  1500 <= df['price'] <= 2499, it doesn't work, while if I use the other form it does... Why? :)

Comment: check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36922103/9177877). It provides a good explanation

Answer (score 2):

Here you should really avoid for loops and if statements. You just want to round to the nearest 500 mark so you could do

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"price":[1200, 1600, 2100, 3499]})

df["price"] = (df["price"]/500).apply(np.floor)*500
```

**EDIT** if you are looking for a more general solution

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"price":[1200, 1600, 2100, 3499,3600, 140000, 160000]})

df["div"] = 5*10**(df["price"].astype(str).str.len()-2)
(df["price"]/df["div"]).apply(np.floor)*df["div"]
```

Comment: that's not quite what I want to do since I have predefined intervals, for bigger values than just what I posted... For example one of my interval is 150000-200000 and for that one it just wont work

Comment: But thanks for your input, I just learnt something useful! :)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: uuuh nice! for this purpouse I shall stick with the simple idea I had, but that solution is way cleaner! thanks!

Comment: I added an example so it will work for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.cut` for that purpose, in your case:

```py
bins=[1000, 1500, 2500, 3000, 4000]

df["bin"]=pd.cut(df["price"], bins, right=False, retbins=False, labels=bins[:-1])
```

Assuming `bin` column is the output column for your function

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html